# Find the surface area of the portion of the hemisphere $f(x,y)=\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}$ that lies above the cylinder $x^2+y^2=9$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Find the surface area of the portion of the hemisphere $f(x,y)=\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}$ that lies above the cylinder $x^2+y^2=9$

To find my limits of integration I did the following:

$$x^2+y^2=9$$

$$y^2=9-x^2$$

$$y=\pm\sqrt{9-x^2}$$

And for $x$, this is $-3\le x\le3$

I then found the the partials as required by the surface area formula:

$$f_x=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}}$$

$$f_y=\frac{-y}{\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}}$$

So I then formed the following double integral:

$$\int^3_{-3}\int^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{9-x^2}}\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{25-x^2-y^2}+\frac{y^2}{25-x^2-y^2}+1}\;dy\;dx$$

Simplifying:

$$\int^3_{-3}\int^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{9-x^2}}\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{25-x^2-y^2}+1}\;dy\;dx$$

Is this double integral set up properly?  If so, hints on how I can solve this double integral?  I tried converting to polar coordinates but was lost as to how to find the limits of integration.

I know the outer limit would be $\int^{2\pi}_{0}$ but the inner limit I'm lost.

Based on the following I'm taking a guess that the inner limit would be $\int^{3}_0$

$$r\;sin\theta=\sqrt{9-r^2cos^2\theta}$$

And when solving this I get $r=3$

Comment: It seems best to convert to polar coordinates. The limits would be $0$ to $3$ and $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: @Element118 does it look like I did everything else correctly?

Comment: Try to substitute $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. I don't think integration will be hard. Then you can check your result using the spherical cap formula ($r=5,a=3,h=1$) here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap.

Comment: @KayK. is it correct to say that I should have the following integral $$\int^{2\pi}_{0} \int^{3}_{0}\sqrt{\frac{25}{25-r^2}}\;r\;dr\;d\theta$$

Comment: @inquisitor, yes I think you're right. I posted the rest of calculation as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$,
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3\frac{5r}{\sqrt{5^2-r^2}}drd\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\left[5\sqrt{5^2-r^2}\right]_3^0d\theta=10\pi$$
Using the already known formula for spherical cap (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) and $r=5,h=1$,

$$A=2\pi rh=10\pi$$
Those two results match.

Comment: One last question, how come you're integrating with respect to $r$ from $3$ to $0$ and not $0$ to $3$ in the last step?  It seems backwards to me.  But if I do it the other way I end up with $-10\pi$

Comment: Actually the integral becomes like this $\int_0^3 \frac{5r}{\sqrt{5^2-r^2}}dr=[-5\sqrt{5^2-r^2}]_0^3$. The minus($-$) comes from $-r^2$. And I removed the minus and instead I swapped $0$ and $3$.